# RegEx for matching a string between some characters?

Tags: regex

I would like to get the text from (character/s) to another (character/s), excluding the searching characters (meaning whatever in between the two searching terms but not including them)

For example this text

```
href="https://old.reddit.com/user/TKayOKAY"> class="author"
```

using the regex /user/(.*?)"/g returned "user/TKayOKAY""

How to remove `user/` and `"` the end double quotes, to get only the username?

basically returning >> TKayOKAY 
for example.

Answer (score 1):

If your regex dialect supports lookarounds, you can use **[lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)** based regex so your full match is the only intend text.

```
(?<=/user/)(.*?)(?=")
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bVT9uf/1)**

OR you can capture your data from group1 using your own regex mentioned in your post.

```
/user/(.*?)"
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bVT9uf/2)**

This demo will show your intended text capture in present in group1

Answer (score 0):

I would decide it so

> /user/([A-z]+)

I have excluded "common" expressions like ". *", In order to avoid subtle problems.
If you see that the string contains only letters, then look for only letters.